# python thread was stopped without exception message

Tags: python, oracle, multithreading, jdbc, raspberry-pi

I'm using Python on Raspberry Pi. And I'm using JDBC to connect to the Oracle database. The problem is that sometimes the thread shuts down while I'm connecting to JDBC. The code is enclosed in a try exception syntax, but the thread is terminated without leaving any exception logs.The reason could not be found because there was no log left. Is there a problem with using JDBC?

```
def connect_A_db(self):
    print('Connect a oracle.db\n')
    try :
        start_time = time.time()
        conn = jaydebeapi.connect("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", dsn, [user, password], jdbc_path)
        period = (time.time() - start_time)
        print("conn_period: " + str(period))
        return conn
    except Exception as ex:
        period = (time.time() - start_time)
        print("conn_period: " + str(period))
        print(str(ex))
        return -1

def A_client_function_send_data(self, msg):
    ret = -1
    try :
        print("start conn")
        t1 = time.time()
        conn = self.connect_A_db()
        if conn != -1:
            cursor = conn.cursor() 
            cursor.execute(msg)
            ret = 0                 
            if isinstance(conn, jaydebeapi.Connection):
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()

                print("%s" %(msg))
                self.logger.debug("%s, ret: %s, %s" %(msg, str(ret), str(time.time() - t1)))
        else:
            ret = -1         

    except jaydebeapi.DatabaseError as e:
        print(f"Insert Error: {e}")
        self.logger.error(f"Insert Error: {e}")
        conn.rollback()
        
    except Exception as ex:
        self.exh.systemError(traceback.format_exc())
        self.logger.error("Exception: " + str(ex))
        print(ex)
        ret = -1
            
    finally :
        print("send ret: "+ str(ret))               
        return ret
```

Based on what remains in the log, the thread is terminated before

`self.logger.debug ("%s, ret: %s, %s"% (msg, str(ret), str(time.time() - t1)))`

runs.

Comment: Thread might be waiting in `commit()` if there are active locks in the database tables. Typically this happens when other systems are accessing the same tables, and without proper synchronization could lead to timeouts and deadlocks.

Comment: Try to keep `print(ex)` only and remove other exception logging. We faced issues accessing Exception object thrown by JayDeBeAPI also (there was something that logger could not process correctly and failed silently)

Comment: Side comment: unless you have a real need for JDBC, try Oracle's native Python driver [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/).

Comment: @astentx Thank you for your answer. I have a question about your answer. Can logging that was working normally cause problems all of a sudden? Is it a problem caused by Jay DeBeAPI? I can't make the same situation because I don't know the cause.

Comment: @BiBi I don't know. The issue was in logging at the server where I don't have an access. `str(exception)` worked well, but some exception methods fail